# How to create a generic container for Patch/Partial<T> Update in SignalR

Tags: c#, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

In short I want to be able to do the following and *not assign* `default() / null` *values to properties not included in the JSON object(a patch object basically)*:

```cs
//                               ↓ -- This is part -- ↓ 
public async Task UpdateCustomer(PartialPatch<Customer> customer)
{ /* Do Work */ }
```

I have tried variations of:

```cs
class Partial<T> : JObject
class Partial<T> : ExpandoObject
class Partial<T> : DynamicObject
```

But all either throw `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type...` or are empty.

Comment: I don't think there is no out of the box solution for such (_patching_ in general) problem. What you can do, is to track the properties which are inside JSON, and then "somehow" exclude those which are not present, when you are doing update operation on your storage

Comment: I can handle the "somehow" exclude..  And I can type the param as just `JObject` and solve from there.  But I need CodeGeneration to be able to know the `<Customer>` part.  Any solution where I inherit from `JObject` or dymanic types fail at cast.   Thats the step I cant get past.

Comment: In HTTP I used code from [OData's Delta class](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http.OData/OData/Delta.cs), but it fails to cast as well in SignalR.